# How to evaluate external go source code "dynamically"?

Tags: go, static-analysis

I need to parse a  Go source code file, find a specific type (by name) and use it in my program. 
 I already managed to find the type I need using the [go/ast](http://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/) package but I don't know how to "load" it into my program so that I can use it.

Question: What's the best way to extract and use a type from an external source code file and use it on runtime?

I can't think of anything except an ugly method to basically copy the file, modify it by injecting a "main" function with my encoding stuff which sends the result to stdOut, execute the it, collect the encoded data from stdout, delete the modified file.

Use case: Analyse go source code and encode the types in a specific format (e.g. json schema)

Edit:
Here is some code. The question is how to encode `type allTypes` (zero value) and then print it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "encoding/json"
)
    var src string = `
package mypack

type allTypes struct{
    Brands Brands
    Colours Colours
}
type Brands struct{
    Sony string
    Apple string
}

type Colours struct{
    Red string
    Green string
}

`
type sometype struct{
    Nothing int
}
func main() {
    // src is the input for which we want to inspect the AST.

    // Create the AST by parsing src.
    fset := token.NewFileSet() // positions are relative to fset
    f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "src.go", src, 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Inspect the AST and find our function
    var tp ast.TypeSpec
    ast.Inspect(f, func(n ast.Node) bool {
        switch x := n.(type) {
        case *ast.TypeSpec:
            if x.Name.Name == "allTypes"{
                tp = *x
            }
        }
        return true
    })

    fmt.Printf("We found the type: it is %v", tp)
    // Encode the zero value of sometype
    x := sometype{}
    b, _ := json.Marshal(&x)
    fmt.Printf("\n Zero value of someType (json) %s", b)
    //Next/Question: How to encode the zero value of "allTypes" ???
}
```

Also on [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/2XjrxKoUdU)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you are asking for dynamic type loading ala Java's `Class.forName(String className)`. The short answer is Go doesn't support this.

The correct way, as Nick Johnson pointed out, is to parse the tree using ast, and then "generate" the JSON yourself. You will not be able to "load" the type and use `JSON.Marshal`. It is also worth noting that any type which supports the `json.Marshaler` interface may generate custom JSON. You also need to ignore, but mark optional "omitempty" behavior. This really prevents you from using the compile it and hack through "stdout" behavior as well.

Comment: would you mind to share a snippet which encodes ``allType`` as provided in the question? The question is actually what's the best way to use solve this problem so I assume that the ast parsing & encoding should be easier than compile & stdout, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract type information at runtime, you need to use the [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package. This is the way Go's `encoding/json` and other similar packages work.

Comment: I'm aware of the reflect package but the question is quite different.

Comment: @Theuserwithnohat then please edit your question and explain how it is different, because the example you've given (JSON schema) can be done with `reflect`.

Comment: The point is that the code is loaded from an external file / source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to operate on the types defined in a Go source file, you can use the [go.parser](http://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/) package to read and parse a source file into an AST, then traverse the AST for the elements you want to examine.

Comment: The issue is how to use the type found in the source code and use it in the current program I'm running  not how to parse the source code. I've edited the question with some code to make sure the issue is understood.

Comment: What do you want to do with it? It's not at all clear from your question what you're trying to ultimately achieve. Depending on your needs, you may simply have to inspect the fields in the type loaded from the source and output the necessary JSON yourself.

Comment: In the example provided in the question I've encoded ``sometype`` which is part of the running program. The question is simply how to encode ``alltype`` too which is not part of the main program(I've loaded the source as a string as the playground doesn't have file access).

Comment: Can you please point me how to do this that?  (inspect the fields in the type loaded from the source and output the necessary JSON). The main issue is that I can't find a way to "load" the type from source code.  As far what I'm trying to do let's say that I want to extract  some types from  a *.go source code file and encode them so that they can serve as "documentation". In the question I've used the json package but I'm actually planning to use json schema which basically "documents" the types for web applications. You may think of this as godoc for web.

Comment: You should expect the `TypeSpec` to contain a `StructType` in its `node` field; you can then iterate over its `FieldList` to get all the fields and their data types, and output those however you wish.

Comment: I need to evaluate the type not to print it. Can you write a snippet which encodes ``type allTypes`` as provided in the question?

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate" in this context? What do you actually need to do with the type?

Comment: I have an example in the question. See the latest comment from the snippet provided. I kinda get what you mean but to me it seems to requires a great amount of effort(maybe I'm overestimating)  so if you can solve the issue from the example provided(encode alltypes which is a "simple" tyoe) I will definitely consider it the right answer.

Comment: As rfilam says in his answer, you can't (practically speaking) load the type and expect the compiler to do it for you - you'll have to inspect the type and output its schema yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to load the type information extracted from the source code(please correct me if I'm wrong).  The only solution is to create/generate a package (main), inject it with all the types extracted from the target source code file, build/compile it, execute it and collect the encoded data from stdout.